# .data('kendoComboBox') returning undefined when called from event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm developing a large scale web app using kendo UI, HTML5, Javascript & Require.js etc.. I'm having trouble figuring out why the call $(selector).data('kendoComboBox') on a jQuery object works in one context but not another. It works just after the successful $(selector).kendoComboBox(parameter.....) create kendo combo box call but not when I call it from an event handler. It appears the kendoComboBox object associated with the object selector is referencing has been lost? Can someone please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be that the jQuery library is loaded again and the widget's data is lost. Other similar issues covered in our [troubleshooting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/troubleshooting) section.

Comment: Hi Petur I discovered that jQuery was being loaded again & when I prevented this from happening the problem was resolved, thank you.

Comment: Whoa, nice catch. Also had a similar problem and this was the fix.